# Magento 2.3.4: How to update composer?

Tags: composer, magento2.3.4, magento-upgrade

Several fatal errors showed up during the upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 from 2.3.4 which, after research, were found to have been caused by the outdated version of composer. Running composer self-update unfortunately doesn't work. Is there a different command or an approach to updating composer to its latest version?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully upgrade my composer version using composer composer self-update

[image]

What issue you are facing.

Comment: This message is what I see when running composer self-update is run.  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: can you please share your screenshot when run command and error message

Comment: Added screenshot showing part of the error messages that I get. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try and reinstall composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

- Download the installer to the current directory
- Verify the installer SHA-384, which you can also cross-check here https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html
- Run the installer
- Remove the installer

Comment: Dominic, could you please add a few lines explaining what exactly this code snippet does? thanks

Comment: Steps to get composer to current dir https://getcomposer.org/download/